# How many draws should one make?

Tags: probability, statistics

Say you have a jar full of $N$ balls numbered from $1,2, \cdots, N.$ And you are allowed to draw as many balls as you like with replacement. Note that $N$ is unknown. How many draws should you make in order know the value of $N?$

I am not sure how to approach this problem. I want to apply probabilistic reasoning, but $N$ is unknown and I can't set up the probability space. Any hints will be much appreciated.

Comment: By the way, the authors are Borwein and Lewis, in case anyone else like me was curious to know which book this is.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for proving this fact?

Comment: Just a wild guess: I would think that you need a separation theorem for proving the second inclusion.